# Clarification over subnormal series of a group

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

I am reading through a lecture note on group theory and it says the following:

Let $H \leq G$ be a subgroup of group $G$. If $G_n \trianglelefteq \cdots \trianglelefteq G_1 = G$ is a subnormal tower of $G$, then $G_n \cap H \trianglelefteq \cdots G_1 \cap H = H$ is a subnormal tower of $H$. Note that $(G_i \cap H) / (G_{i+1} \cap H) \hookrightarrow G_i/G_{i+1}$. If $N \trianglelefteq G$, then $G_nN \trianglelefteq \cdots \trianglelefteq G_1N = G$ is a subnormal tower. Note that $G_i/G_{i+1} \twoheadrightarrow (G_iN)/(G_{i+1}N)$.

I get that the two induced towers are subnormal towers. However, I do not get what the lecturer means by $(G_i \cap H) / (G_{i+1} \cap H) \hookrightarrow G_i/G_{i+1}$ and that $G_i/G_{i+1} \twoheadrightarrow (G_iN)/(G_{i+1}N)$, because (for example) $(G_i \cap H) / (G_{i+1} \cap H)$ clearly is not a subgroup of $G_i/G_{i+1}$. Can anyone clarify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a typo. The $C_{i+1}$ should be $G_{i+1}$, and the intersection symbol between $(G_i\cap H)$ and $(G_{i+1}\cap H)$ should be a quotient symbol. That is, the statement says/is trying to say that under the given hypotheses,
$$\frac{G_i\cap H}{G_{i+1}\cap H}\hookrightarrow \frac{G_i}{G_{i+1}}.$$
Note that this assertion does not require the left hand side to be *subgroup* of $G_i/G_{i+1}$: it requires that there be an injective group homomorphism.

The injective group homomorphism is the following:  given $x\in G_i\cap H$, map $x(G_{i+1}\cap H)$ to $xG_{i+1}$.

This is well-defined and injective, since for $x,y\in H\cap G_i$,
$$\begin{align*}
x(G_{i+1}\cap H) = y(G_{i+1}\cap H)&\iff y^{-1}x\in G_{i+1}\cap H\\
&\iff y^{-1}x\in G_{i+1}\\
&\iff xG_{i+1}=yG_{i+1}.
\end{align*}$$
And it is a group homomorphism because the product of the class of $x$ and the class of $y$ is the class of $xy$.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your post. For surjection $G_i/G_{i+1} \twoheadrightarrow (G_iN)/(G_{i+1}N)$, What I did was to notice that, with $N' := G_{i+1}N$ and $H:= N$, we have $HN'/N' \cong H/H \cap N'$ by 2nd isomorphism theorem and then noticed that that this is equal to $G_iN / G_{i+1}N \cong G_i/(G_{i+1}(G_{i+1}N \cap G_i))$, and we can then create the obvious surjection from $G_i/G_{i+1}$ to $G_i/(G_{i+1}(G_{i+1}N \cap G_i))$. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Love_and_light The map $G_iN\to G_iN/G_{i+1}N$ is surjective; and $g_in$ has the same image as $g_i$, because $G_{i+1}N=NG_{i+1}$, so $g_in(G_{i+1}N) = g_in(NG_{i+1}) = g_i(NG_{i+1}) = g_i(G_{i+1}N)$. So the map $G_i\to G_iN/G_{i+1}N$ is surjective; $G_{i+1}$ lies in the kernel, so it factors through $G_i/G_{i+1}$.